# Using the TAG command to search for a img without clicing?

Tags: imacros

I have a web where an image is shown and when clicked it starts the uploading process to upload picture. I would like to be able to check if this image exist but without clicking it. The TAG command seems to always click the element it selects. Is there any possibility to avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use extract in tag command to prevent it from clicking, something like this:

```
tag pos=1 type=img attr=txt:* extract=txt
```